# ReturnKeyType data type in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

In my react-native application, I use typescript. When I pass the returnKeyType as a prop, I have to set the type of the returnKeyType.

```
<TextInput
 editable={editable}
 returnKeyType={returnKeyType}
 maxLength={maxLength}
/>
```

My interface is like this.

```
interface IProps extends Props<IProps> {
  editable?: boolean;
  maxLength?: number;
  returnKeyType: string;
}
```

When I set the returnKeyType to string, it gives an error like this.

```
"Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"none" | "done" | "search" | "default" | "go" | "next" | "send" | "previous" | "google" | "join" | "route" | "yahoo" | "emergency-call" | undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1438, 5): The expected type comes from property 'returnKeyType' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TextInput> & Readonly<TextInputProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode}>"
```

How can I set the type here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returnKeyType is an enum, so you should be able to do the following:

```
interface IProps extends Props<IProps> {
  editable?: boolean;
  maxLength?: number;
  returnKeyType: "none" | "done" | "search" | "default" | "go" | "next" | "send" | "previous" | "google" | "join" | "route" | "yahoo" | "emergency-call";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than listing all of the types out yourself, it would be better to just import and use the type from React Native. This means your type will correctly reflect any future changes they make across react native versions (e.g. if they added a new return key type, your interface would keep working), and also means you can't accidentally miss a type, etc.

```
import { ReturnKeyTypeOptions } from "react-native";

interface IProps extends Props<IProps> {
  editable?: boolean;
  maxLength?: number;
  returnKeyType: ReturnKeyTypeOptions;
}
```